# Tracing program in assembly.

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I'am trying to understand how a C program looks like at assembly level so i run gdb and used disassemble on main and get_input. The program is short so that i can follow it better. 
There are 2 lines that i don't understand. First on in main() is:

`0x00000000004005a3 <+4>:  mov    $0x0,%eax`

We save the old value of rbp and save current value of rsp to rbp. What is the purpose of that instruction?

The other in get_input() is:

```
000000000400581 <+4>:   sub    $0x10,%rsp
```

Here too we start by saving old value of rbp, by pushing it to the stack. Then giving rbp the current value of rsp. Then 16 bytes are subtracted from rsp. I understand this is space allocated but why is it 16 bytes and not 8 bytes? I made the buffer 8 bytes only, what are the purpose of the other 8 bytes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void get_input()
{
    char buffer[8];

    gets(buffer);
    puts(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    get_input();
    return 0;
}
```

Dump of assembler code for function main:

```
   0x000000000040059f <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004005a0 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004005a3 <+4>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005a8 <+9>: callq  0x40057d <get_input>
   0x00000000004005ad <+14>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005b2 <+19>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004005b3 <+20>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Dump of assembler code for function get_input:

```
   0x000000000040057d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040057e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400581 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400585 <+8>: lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400589 <+12>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040058c <+15>:    callq  0x400480 <gets@plt>
   0x0000000000400591 <+20>:    lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400595 <+24>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400598 <+27>:    callq  0x400450 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040059d <+32>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000040059e <+33>:    retq
```

Comment: The `mov $0x0, %eax` is the `return 0` as return values are placed in `eax` according to calling convention. As for the 16 bytes, that's stack alignment, also prescribed by the calling convention.

Comment: @Jester, you are just too darned fast for me. Every time I try to post something you've got something up here by the time I finish writing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `main()`...

```
0x000000000040059f <+0>: push   %rbp
```

Push `%RBP`'s value onto the stack.

```
0x00000000004005a0 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

Copy `%RSP`'s value into `%RBP` (create a new stack frame).

```
0x00000000004005a3 <+4>: mov    $0x0,%eax
```

Move the immediate value `0x0` into `%EAX`. That is, it zeroes `%EAX`. As you're in 64-bit mode, this also clears all of `%RAX`.

```
0x00000000004005a8 <+9>: callq  0x40057d <get_input>
```

Push `%RIP`'s value (undoable directly), then jump to label/function `get_input()`.

```
0x00000000004005ad <+14>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
```

According to the [AMD64 System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), a function's return value is stored in `%RAX` (not taking into account floating point and large structures). It also says that there are two groups of registers: caller-saved and callee-saved. When you call a function, you can't expected caller-saved registers to remain the same, you must save them yourself in the stack if necessary. Likewise, a function that gets called must preserve callee-saved registers if it uses them. The caller-saved registers are `%RAX`, `%RDI`, `%RSI`, `%RDX`, `%RCX`, `%R8`, `%R9`, `%R10`, and `%R11`. The callee-saved registers are `%RBX`, `%RSP`, `%RBP`, `%R12`, `%R13`, `%R14`, and `%R15`.

Now, as `main()` apparently performs `return 0`, it must return that `0` in `%RAX`, right? However, two things should be taken into account. Firstly, in the AMD64 System V ABI, `sizeof(int) == 4`. `%RAX` is 8 bytes wide, but `%EAX` is 4 bytes wide, so `%EAX` should be used for manipulating `int`-wide stuff, such as `main()`'s return value. Secondly, `%EAX` is part of `%RAX`, and `%RAX` is caller-saved, thus we can't rely on its value after a call. So, we perform `MOV $0x0, %EAX` in order to set the function's return value to zero.

```
0x00000000004005b2 <+19>:    pop    %rbp
```

Restore `main()`'s caller's `%RBP`, that is, destroy `main()`'s stack frame.

```
0x00000000004005b3 <+20>:    retq
```

Return from `main()` with a return value of `0`.

Then, we have `get_input()`...

```
0x000000000040057d <+0>: push   %rbp
```

Push `%RBP`'s value onto the stack.

```
0x000000000040057e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

Copy `%RSP`'s value into `%RBP` (create a new stack frame).

```
0x0000000000400581 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
```

Subtract 16 from `%RSP` (reserve 16 bytes of temporary storage for the current frame).

```
0x0000000000400585 <+8>: lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
```

Load the effective address `-0x10(%RBP)` into `%RAX`. That is, it loads into `%RAX` the result of subtracting 16 from `%RBP`'s value. This means that `%RAX` now points to the first byte of local temporary storage.

```
0x0000000000400589 <+12>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
```

According to the ABI, a function's first argument is given on `%RDI`, the second on `%RSI`, etc... In this case, `%RAX`'s value is given as the first argument to the to-be-called function.

```
0x000000000040058c <+15>:    callq  0x400480 <gets@plt>
```

Call function `gets()`.

```
0x0000000000400591 <+20>:    lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
```

The same as above.

```
0x0000000000400595 <+24>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
```

Pass `%RAX` as the first argument.

```
0x0000000000400598 <+27>:    callq  0x400450 <puts@plt>
```

Call function `puts()`.

```
0x000000000040059d <+32>:    leaveq
```

Equivalent to `MOV %RBP, %RSP` then `POP %RBP`, that is, destroys the stack frame.

```
0x000000000040059e <+33>:    retq
```

Return from function `get_input()` without a proper return value.

Now...

> `MOV $0x0, %EAX`
>   What is the purpose of that instruction?

The second instance of that instruction is quite important, as it sets the return value of `main()`. However, the first one is actually redundant. You probably have optimizations disabled on your compiler.

> Then 16 bytes are subtracted from rsp. I understand this is space allocated but why is it 16 bytes and not 8 bytes? I made the buffer 8 bytes only, what are the purpose of the other 8 bytes?

The ABI requires that `%RSP` shall be positioned on a 16-byte boundary before each function call. BTW, you should get away from statically-sized buffers and `gets()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go into it step by step, all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The first instruction, `mov $0x0, %eax`, moves a zero into EAX in order to set the return code.

The second instruction, `sub $0x10,%rsp` is allocating memory and aligning the stack for system calls.  The calling standard requires 16 byte alignment, not 8.